# Understanding generic in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am building some generic codes which returning a collection of any type of object. Here is my build:

```
public class Util{
    public static <T, R extends Collection> R a(Collection<T> collection) {
        return (R) collection;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> listWith(T... items) {
        return Arrays.asList(items);
    }

    public static <T> Set<T> setWith(T... items) {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    }
}
```

My Idea is from this Util class I can create any list or set of any object type, something like:

```
List<String> list = a(listWith("str1", "str2"));
Set<Object> set = a(setWith(new Object(), new Object()));
```

I have now two questions:

1. How can I restrict the type of the Obj in the left to be the same as the Obj type of the parameter passed to the `listWith` method? Because right now I can do something like : `Set<String> set = a(setWith(new Object(), new Object()));` without any compile error
2. How can I restrict the return type of the `a` method to be **only class that extends the Collection**. Right now I can do something like: `User user = a(listWith("test"));` also without compile error but then it will throw an casting exception. I did try above with return type as `R extends Collection` but it did not success

Comment: do not use raw types, change generic types definition to `<T, R extends Collection<T>>` and you will get compile time error.

Comment: The problem with `a` is that the type is chosen at the call site. For example, you could do both `List<String> list = a(something); Set<String> set = a(something);` - and at least one of those will likely fail, because `something` is likely not both a `Set` and a `List`. In that case, it is better just to do an explicit cast where you would otherwise invoke `a`.

Comment: `<T, R extends Collection<T>> R a(Collection<T> collection)` but why not returning it directly in listWith and setWith methods? Also why wrapping asList with a different name? asSet would be a good enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > How can I restrict the type of the Obj in the left to be the same as the Obj type of the parameter passed to the listWith method?

   Don't use a raw type of the `Collection` and restrict it to the generic type.

   ```
   public static <T, R extends Collection<T>> R a(Collection<T> collection) { 
       return (R) collection;
   }
   ```

   But it can be designed better (look below).
2. > How can I restrict the return type of the a method to be only class that extends the Collection. Right now I can do something like: User user = a(listWith("test")); also without compile error but then it will throw an casting exception.

   Remember the class `User` *might* implement `Collection` in the future and compiler doesn't check this information at the compile time.

   Further restriction will do that. If the `R` is a subtype of `Collection<T>` and the very same collection is required as an input parameter, you can ask for `R collection` and return it without explicit casting.

   ```
    public static <T, R extends Collection<T>> R a(R collection) {
        return collection;
    }
   ```

After applying the 2nd part of the answer:

```
List<String> list = a(listWith("str1", "str2"));           // compiles
Set<Object> set = a(setWith(new Object(), new Object()));  // compiles

Set<String> set2 = a(setWith(new Object(), new Object())); // doesn't compile
User user = a(listWith("test"));                           // doesn't compile
```

This restriction is valid for this simple case but doesn't make sense at all. You can find a further explanation at @DmytroMitin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63923409/3764965).

As you can see, the whole application of the #2 finally *returns the input itself*, which it gives me a question:

**"Is such generic wrapping needed?**":

```
List<String> list = listWith("str1", "str2");
Set<Object> set = setWith(new Object(), new Object());
```

Comment: I guess also  a question can be **why** with the fix #1 `User user = a(listWith("test"));` compiles.

Comment: Also in your fix #2 `a` can be made trivial (returning the same collection). Suppose `a` does some work: `public static <T, R extends Collection<Tuple<T, T>>> R a(Collection<T> collection) { Collection<Tuple<T, T>> res = ...; for (T t: collection) { res.add(new Tuple<>(t, t)); } return (R) res; }`. In such case fix #2 seems impossible. But `User user = a(listWith("test"));` compiles. So this doesn't answer OP's second question how to restrict the return type to be only class that extends the Collection.

Comment: Your code is not compliant with my 2nd fix. What I suggest is `a(R collection)` while you stick back with `a(Collection<T> collection)`. Thus the method actually *doing* something `public static <T, R extends Collection<T>> R a(R collection) { Collection<Tuple<T, T>> res = new ArrayList<>(); for (T t: collection) { res.add(new Tuple<>(t, t)); } return (R) res; }` doesn't let `User user = a(listWith("test"));` compile.

Comment: Yeap but this signature is a lie (possible because of casting). Actually you accept a subtype of `Collection<T>` and return a subtype of `Collection<Tuple<T, T>>`. With correct signature `public static <T, R extends Collection<T>, R1 extends Collection<Tuple<T, T>>> R1 a(R collection)` `User user = a(listWith("test"));` still compiles.

Comment: I finally see where do you aim at. The real purpose of my answer is the process of getting into the last step: omitting the whole wrapper. I don't think it's possible to really restrict the return type in such case.

Comment: I will refer to your answer which rather focuses to that part.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add to **@Nikolas**'s answer why with his fix #1

```
public static <T, R extends Collection<T>> R a(Collection<T> collection) { 
    return (R) collection;
}
```

`User user = a(listWith("test"));` still compiles i.e. why `R extends Collection<T>` doesn't restrict enough the return type so that it still can be `User`.

I guess the thing is that the type parameters `T, R` of the method `a` can be inferred like

```
User user = Util.<String, User & Collection<String>>a(listWith("test"));
```

Here `Util.<String, User & Collection<String>>a...` seems to be not valid syntax but if we define

```
class User {}
class SubUser extends User implements Collection<String>{ ... }
```

then

```
User user = Util.<String, SubUser>a(listWith("test"));
```

is possible.

---

Regarding your 2nd question

> How can I restrict the return type of the `a` method to be only class that extends the Collection.

Generally this seems impossible because for every class `User` its subclass

```
class SubUser<T> extends User implements Collection<T> {...}
```

is still possible.